# How to internationalize firefox extension

Tags: firefox, internationalization, firefox-addon

I want to internationalize my firefox extension. So I include

```
<!DOCTYPE page SYSTEM "chrome://myextension/locale/overlay.dtd">
```

which contains e.g.

```
<!ENTITY myLabel "Test">
```

Now setting

```
<label value="&myLabel;"/>
```

gives me an error at the line above at the position of the bold char < l a b e **l**

[image]

Manifest:

```
content   smsflatrate                 chrome/content/
skin      smsflatrate   classic/1.0   chrome/skin/
locale    smsflatrate   en-US         chrome/locale/en-US/


overlay   chrome://browser/content/browser.xul   chrome://smsflatrate/content/ff-overlay.xul
style chrome://global/content/customizeToolbar.xul chrome://smsflatrate/skin/overlay.css
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Does the error say something in particular? Make sure you still have valid XML.

Comment: can you give us full error, also look at file's encoding

Comment: I have updated my question with the error message

Comment: It says Nicht definierte Entitat (looks like Entity not Defined) - meaning your appkeylabel is not defined in DTD or the file is in the wrong place (e.g. your chrome manifest is incorrect) - or you don't have it for the language in question, send us your chrome.manifest if this did not help

Comment: I used the generator to create a basic extension, all predefined entities work. I just added mine and referenced it in the sidebar.xul like shown above but I get that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add:

```
<!ENTITY appkeylabel  "missing">
```

at the end of your overlay.dtd, you're missing that entity.